# React Native Custom Font Issues 0.63.4

Tags: react-native, fonts, styles

I cant seem to link the fonts properly and i've checked all my code 5 times..... I need help!

App.js -

```
 <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Poppins-Black' }}>InviteUs</Text>
```

Info.PList -

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>Poppins-Black.ttf</string>
        <string>Gilroy-ExtraBold.otf</string>
    </array>
```

react-native.config.js -

```
module.exports = {
    project: {
        ios: {},
        android: {}, // grouped into "project"
    },
    assets: ["./assets/fonts/"], // stays the same
};
```

Font Name -

```
assets/fonts/Poppins-Black.ttf
```

PostScript Name -

```
Poppins-Black
```

Comment: Did you run `react-native link` command?

Comment: @LeriGogsadze i dont believe i need to because i'm in react native 0.63, right?

Comment: Did you manually link those fonts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you add your custom font to Copy Bundle Resourse like this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create folder called fonts inside assets folder and place your font types inside that assets folder.

Then create `react-native.config.js` and like as following,

```
module.exports = {
    project: {
        ios: {},
        android: {}, // grouped into "project"
    },
    assets: ["./src/assets/fonts/"], // stays the same
};
```

After run react-native link(for our own links this should be)

Finally restart your npm and run app again